# Swiping with rigidbody

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics

My character moves continuously forward with

```
rigidbody.velocity = v3Force * strength;
```

My Swipe script is based on a youtube tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZIHx09GevI

I just changed the end result with

```
rigidbody.AddForce(v2Force * strength1);
```

For Right Swipe and below for Left Swipe

```
rigidbody.AddForce(v1Force * strength1);
```

Here are the vForce variables :

```
var v1Force : Vector3 = -transform.right;
var v2Force : Vector3 = transform.right;
var v3Force : Vector3 = transform.forward;
```

The swipe works fine, but the result isn't what I'm aiming for because when I swipe left/right my character seems to be moving only one frame left/right. And then continues moving forward. When I disable the forward movement, the swipe works great and makes my character move right/left for a period of time, after I swipe.

My question is how do I reach this result(moving sideways more than just a frame) with my continuous forward movement enabled?

Comment: Are you calling that code in the FixedUpdate method? Post the vForce variable too... You're a little scarce on the detail

Comment: I was calling it in the FixedUpdate but now I just put it in the Update function.